# Сериализация коллекции объектов (List) с связями в XML

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация

Я столкнулся с проблемой сериализации объектов с связями в XML. Допустим у меня есть:

```
[Serializable]
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Catalog> Catalogs { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Catalogs = new List<Catalog>();
    }
}
```

Далее

```
[Serializable]
public class File
{
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CatalogId { get; set; }
    public Catalog Catalog { get; set; }
}
```

И

```
[Serializable]
public class Catalog
{
    public int CatalogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? RootCatalogId { get; set; }
    public Catalog RootCatalog { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
    public Catalog()
    {
        Files = new List<File>();
    }
}
```

Далее 
Имитирую заполнение:

```
        var user = new User()
        {
            UserId = 1,
            Name = "first"
        };


        var catalog1 = new Catalog()
        {
            CatalogId = 1,
            Name = "first",
            User = user,
            UserId = user.UserId
        };

        var catalog2 = new Catalog()
        {
            CatalogId = 2,
            Name = "second",
            User = user,
            UserId = user.UserId,
            RootCatalog = catalog1,
            RootCatalogId = catalog1.CatalogId
        };

        user.Catalogs.Add(catalog1);
        user.Catalogs.Add(catalog2);

        var file1 = new File() {
            Name = "first",
            FileId = 1,
            Catalog=catalog1,
            CatalogId=catalog1.CatalogId
        };

        catalog1.Files.Add(file1);


        var file2 = new File()
        {
            Name = "second",
            FileId = 2,
            Catalog = catalog2,
            CatalogId = catalog2.CatalogId
        };
        catalog2.Files.Add(file2);
```

Далее сериализация:

```
            XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(User));

            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("xmltest.xml");

            xml.Serialize(writer,user);
```

И вуоля ошибка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ругается на что?

Comment: @tym32167 на тип данных List<Catalog>

Comment: какой текст ошибки?

Comment: @tym32167, правильно ли я понимаю. Что при сериализации, лучше игнорировать связи на другие объекты?

Comment: нет, не правильно. При сериелизации не так важно как вы её делаете, как то, какой результат на выходе имеете.

Comment: @tym32167, добавил информации, потому что понимаю, дал ее в начале мало.

Comment: Вам явно написано, что `ICollection<T>` не сериализуется. Поменяйте это на `List<T>` или vна массив, то есть на конкретный класс, а не интерфейс.

Comment: @tym32167, а связь не разрушится? Я описал вам модели БД. Я как читал, там связь 1 к многим описывают через ICollection

Comment: ещё обратите внимание, что у вас у каталога есть ссылка на файл, а у файла есть ссылка на каталог - как вы эту циклическую связь видите в XML?

Comment: Вы что, модель данных сериализуете? Для сериализации я бы предложил написать отдельные сущности.

Comment: Да... Необходимо забрать все данные по конкретному пользователю и сериализовать в json, xml. Если с json я могу отключить данные связи при сериализации(не уверен, что это верно). Но с XML я в тупике.

Comment: @tym32167, по поводу создать отдельные сущности была мысль, но как переписывать. Это не слишком затратно то,  и нуторно будет?

Comment: Вы можете [решить проблему](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3815539/312041) с циклическими ссылками аттрибутами и вам не обязательно для этого писать отдельные классы, но я бы просто советовал вам разделять мухи и котлеты - модель БД она не для сериализации, а для общения с БД.

Comment: @tym32167, абсолютно согласен. просто столкнулся с данным кейсом. к сожалению не я придумал)

Comment: @tym32167, Спасибо большое, однако осталось только одна проблема, это ICollection.

Comment: Просто так это не побороть, надо [немного накостылить](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoftwareDoneRight/archive/2008/01/16/how-to-serialize-an-interface-using-the-xmlserializer.aspx), а то может и вообще кастомный сериализатор писать.

Comment: @tym32167, я знаю что при сериализации в json, в случае интерфейса мы можем ему указать резолвить данную ситуацию самостоятельно, либо с указаннием конкретных типов, и там это прекрасно работает(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы обратил внимание на три момента.

Во-первых, нельзя сериализовать интерфейсы. Зачем вам свойство типа ICollection, когда вы все равно его инициализируете списком? Сделайте это свойство типа `List<T>`.

Во-вторых, сериализация не производится при  наличии циклических ссылок. У вас же юзер ссылается на каталоги, а каталоги на юзера. Каталог ссылается на рут, а он на свои каталоги. Каталог ссылается на файлы, а файл на каталог. Не нужно сериализовать свойства со ссылками на эти объекты. При десериализации придется восстанавливать ссылки по ID.
Как-то так:

```
[Serializable]
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public List<Catalog> Catalogs { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Catalogs = new List<Catalog>();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class File
{
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CatalogId { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Catalog Catalog { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Catalog
{
    public int CatalogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? RootCatalogId { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Catalog RootCatalog { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public User User { get; set; }

    public List<File> Files { get; set; }

    public Catalog()
    {
        Files = new List<File>();
    }
}
```

И в-третьих, вы используете System.IO, в котором уже есть класс `File`. Я бы переименовал ваш собственный класс `File` или, обращаясь к нему, явно указывал пространство имен. Пока, по-видимому, ваш класс `File` и класс с методом, где происходит сериализация, находятся в одном пространстве имен. В этой ситуации все будет работать. Но я бы поправил во избежание дальнейших коллизий.